# Uploading Images from React Native to Firebase Storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I am getting images from my phone gallery using React Native Image Picker Library, the images are in base64 format, when I try to upload them to firebase storage, they do not display, I have tried various solutions but none of them work here they are :

```
const response = await fetch(result.assets[0].uri)
const blob = response.blob()

uploadBytes(imgRef, blob).then((snapshot)=>{
    getDownloadURL(ref(storage, result.assets[0].fileName))
    .then((url) => {
        url_ = url;
        userDetails.update_details("image_1", url_);
    })
})
```

This one stores an octet stream

```
const binaryData = Buffer.from(result.assets[0].base64, "base64");
const blob = new Blob([binaryData], { type: 'image/png' });

uploadBytes(imgRef, blob).then((snapshot)=>{
    getDownloadURL(ref(storage, result.assets[0].fileName))
    .then((url) => {
        url_ = url;
        userDetails.update_details("image_1", url_);
    })
})
```

This saves the image as png but it does not open on firebase console.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem was that the base64 image was not properly being converted to a blob.
I have used this function to convert base64 image to blob properly:

```
const getBlobFromUri = async (uri) => {
    const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.onload = function () {
             resolve(xhr.response);
          };
          xhr.onerror = function (e) {
             reject(new TypeError("Network request failed"));
          };
          xhr.responseType = "blob";
          xhr.open("GET", uri, true);
          xhr.send(null);
       });
          
    return blob;
};
```